# Using TSQL, can I increment a CHAR(1) column by one and use it in a LEFT OUTER JOIN without a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, algorithm, t-sql

This question is similar to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899502/can-i-use-sql-to-find-missing-numbers-in-the-example-table-i-give-below).  Except this time I'm using letters rather than 6 digit integers. I want to find the out of sequence "letters".

Let's say I have the following data:

```
id | Date | Letter
-----------------------------
01 | 5/1/2009 | X
02 | 5/1/2009 | Y
03 | 5/1/2009 | Z
04 | 5/1/2009 | A
05 | 5/1/2009 | B
06 | 5/1/2009 | D
```

I would like to be able to come up with a query that would tell me there should be a row with "C" in between row 05 and 06.

In my last question (using INTs) I was offered something similar to the following solution, and it worked great.

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.INTCol - 1 = t2.INTCol AND t1.date = t2.date
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Well, with letters (as far as I know) I can't say (G - 1).  So, is there another way I can do this?

The database I am using is SQL Server 2005.  I believe there is an easy solution in PL/SQL that uses TRANSLATE, but I don't thing I can do anything like using TSQL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert the char(1) to its ascii number using

```
ASCII(Letter)
```

You can then increment this by one and return it to a letter using CHAR (if necessary), so your code would be this:

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 
      ON ASCII(t1.INTCol) - 1 = ASCII(t2.INTCol) 
      AND t1.date = t2.date
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ASCII() function to convert a character to its ASCII value:

**ASCII(Letter)**