# Increment an alpha string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using a string of characters which I need to periodically increment to the next letter.

If the letter goes past `z` it needs to add another 'digit', so for example:

- a => b
- b => c
- z => aa
- aa => ab
- az => ba
- zz => aaa

...etc

It would be really useful to have a function to do this.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938357/using-tsql-can-i-increment-a-char1-column-by-one-and-use-it-in-a-left-outer-j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IncrementString
(
    @String varchar(10)
)
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @LastChar   char,
            @Remainder  varchar(50)

    SELECT  @LastChar   = RIGHT(@String, 1)
    IF      LEN(@String) > 1
            SELECT      @Remainder  = LEFT(@String, LEN(@String)-1 )
    ELSE
            SELECT      @Remainder  = ''

    IF      @LastChar   NOT BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z'
    BEGIN
        RETURN ''
    END

    IF      @LastChar = 'z'
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @LastChar = 'a'
        IF      @Remainder = ''
            SELECT  @Remainder = 'a'
        ELSE
            SELECT  @Remainder = dbo.IncrementString( @Remainder )
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @LastChar = CHAR( 97 + (ASCII( @LastChar ) - 96) )
    END

    RETURN  @Remainder + @LastChar
END
GO
```

For example the following will display all sequences from `a` to `zzz`:

```
DECLARE @Chars varchar(10)
SET @Chars = 'a'

WHILE   @Chars <> 'aaaa'
BEGIN
    PRINT   @Chars
    SELECT  @Chars = dbo.IncrementString( @Chars )
END
```

Comment: Be careful porting this between servers or databases with different collations; your results may not be what you expect.  Also, this will only work with non-Unicode strings.  You'll have issues feeding your function Unicode data. Finally, you've defined a scalar function.  If you ever need to use thing in a large set, you may run into performance issues.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli All good points. Luckily for me none of those apply, but important to remember.

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G If you're not spending time down at Moes could you check this question out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75639172/create-and-increment-an-alpha-characters-but-without-using-numbers

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Question, Please try with below script, I believe that will help you.

```
    Declare @Input AS VARCHAR(10)='AZZZZ'
    DECLARE @Len AS INT
    SELECT @Len=LEN(@Input)

    ;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len, 1) Alphabet
            ,CASE 
            WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len, 1))-64 < 26 THEN CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len, 1))+1)
            ELSE 'A' END AS New
           ,CASE 
            WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Input, @Len, 1))-64 < 26 THEN 0
            ELSE 1 END AS iscarryForward        
            ,@Len Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, Number-1, 1) Alphabet
           ,CASE 
            WHEN iscarryForward=1 AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Input, Number-1, 1))-64 < 26 THEN CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Input, Number-1, 1))+1)
            WHEN iscarryForward=0 THEN SUBSTRING(@Input, Number-1, 1) 
            ELSE 'A' END AS New
           ,CASE 
            WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Input, Number-1, 1))-64 < 26 THEN 0
            ELSE 1 END AS iscarryForward        
            ,Number-1 Number
            FROM CTE WHERE Number > 1   

    )
    SELECT 
    * FROM CTE 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '' Alphabet,'A' New ,0 iscarryForward,0 Number  FROM CTE 
           HAVING SUM(iscarryForward)=@Len
```

Please go through this and change based on your requirement now ..